# How to make my program read a line from text file?

Tags: c#

I am making an account checker and I have no idea how to make my program accept user input.I want user to make a .txt file under a certain name and than program should read a line from that file and use it in some areas of my program(In the code you can see where).

The program Im making is a minecraft name checker and it suppose to tell user is certain name availble or not.Previously I have searched web far and wide for the solution of my problem but with no luck :(

```
class Program
{
    static Regex Availability = new Regex(@"<div class=""col-lg-5 text-center my-1""><div class=""row no-gutters align-items-center""><div class=""col-sm-6 my-1""><div><strong>Status</strong></div><div>(.+?)</div></div>");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        args = new[]
        {
            "https://namemc.com/search?q=(Line from txt file)"
        };

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var content = ScrubContent(client.DownloadString(args[0]));

            var available = Availability.Matches(content).Cast<Match>().Single().Groups[1];

            Console.WriteLine("The name (line from txt file) is {0}", available);
        }
    }

    static string ScrubContent(string content)
    {
        return new string(content.Where(c => c != '\n').ToArray());
    }
}
```

Lets say first line in our .txt file is jeans console should print

> The name Jeans is Unavailable

But now for example the first line of my file is availablename9 console should print

> The name availablename9 is Available

Comment: Please provide clarity.  Do you only want first line of file or do you want to check availability of all names in the file where each name is on its own line.

Comment: well i would like to check availability of all names form the file but currently I dont know how to code a cycles so Im gonna just ask you to help me with making my program only reading first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the file is going to be small, there's a convenient 'File' class you can use to get all of the lines of a particular file, retrieve the first one. It would look like this:

```
//Make sure to add System.IO namespace, if not already present:
//using System.IO;

var file = new File.ReadLines("C:\Path\To\File.txt");
var firstLine = file.FirstOrDefault();
```

If the file is going to be larger, it will be more memory efficient to use a StreamReader and go through the lines 1 by 1, but this should work fine for your purposes.

Comment: will is there another way to clerify the directory cause I plan on releasing this and not all people will save it in the same directory

Comment: Ideally, you should get the file path from the user, and pass it into file like this:
 var file = new File(filePath);. If you don't want to get input from the user, you could instruct them to always put the file in the same folder as the program you're creating, in which case you could access it like this: new File(@".\File.txt"). That should find a file called "File.txt" in the same folder as the application. How are you planning on determining where each user's file will be?

Comment: No problem. Also, here's an example of what I think you're going to want, including a loop to go through each line of a file: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xw90Fg

Comment: I get this error when I try to run the code System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=0x80131508
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\[Redacted]\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 20

Comment: I updated line 20 of that code - copy the change over and try it again. It's probably because the args array is present, but empty - the change I added will check for that before it tries to use it.

Comment: @Joseph.  You should post the full code here as links can go stale.

Comment: The question asked in comments was unrelated to the original question, so I did not want to update my answer to add it in. This code was meant specifically for BataBo as opposed to being for the answer to the question, so I did not intend for the link to be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt");
```

---

FYI this is better

```
static string ScrubContent(string content)
{
    return content.Split('\n')[0];
}
```

Comment: He did state he only wants the first line - would probably be better to use ReadLines to retrieve the full list of lines, then keep only the first one.